# sqlite3-ruby install error on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, sqlite, sqlite3-ruby

I have the following error during sqlite3-ruby install:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3-ruby:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal' or 'yum install sqlite3-devel'
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby1.8
    --with-sqlite3-dir
    --without-sqlite3-dir
    --with-sqlite3-include
    --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
    --with-sqlite3-lib
    --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.3.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.3.1/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
```

sqlite3.h is located in /usr/include/

```
sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby --without-sqlite3-include=/usr/include
```

doesn't work

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
    invalid option: --without-sqlite3-include=/usr/include
```

Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: same issue - this is not answered.

sqlite3.h is non-existent and all the above packages are installed.

ubunut 10.10

Comment: Try to sudo apt-get install build-essential and then sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby

Comment: it has since changed to just `sqlite3`, not `sqlite3-ruby`

Comment: Worked for me on ubuntu 12.04 as marshluca suggested. sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev

Answer (score 598, accepted):

You need the SQLite3 development headers for the gem’s native extension to compile against. You can install them by running (possibly with `sudo`):

```
apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

Comment: I needed `sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev` . Thanks.

Comment: Thanks—this definitely would not have been obvious.

Answer (score 16):

You just need a `--` in there.

```
sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby -- --with-sqlite3-include=/usr/include
```

That specifies that the option is not to gem directly, but the specific gem.

Answer (score 10):

In my case I have no basic compilers installed, so

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

solved my problem, but for most the people I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/3649005/417267 is the solution.

Comment: This was my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

This is what I did:

```
wget http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-amalgamation-3.7.2.tar.gz
tar xzf sqlite-amalgamation-3.7.2.tar.gz
cd sqlite-3.7.2/

./configure
make
make install

gem install rails sqlite3-ruby
```

from : http://cuasan.wordpress.com/2010/10/13/rails-3-on-debian-with-sqlite-3/

Comment: This still works 10 years later! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If you run in ubuntu,and using RVM for ruby on rails,please add FIRST:

```
sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev
```

OR You can check with these commands:

This command will prepare for you two packages : sqllite3 and libsqlite3-dev

> sudo apt-get install sqlite3
>   libsqlite3-dev

-Now,install sqlite gem

```
 [sudo] gem install sqlite3-ruby
```

-using Ubuntu doesn't need sudo.

Goodluck! Note: i'm using Ubuntu 10.10 and it's working.

Answer (score 6):

This was simply enough to make it work

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

Thanks to marshluca

Answer (score 4):

Tried *ALL* of other solutions, none helped.

It turned out that you also need dev package for ruby itself. For me, it helped

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-full
```

It has a lot of nasty dependencies though (like emacs, wtf?), just

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.8-dev
```

should be fine. After it's installed (and you have the sqlite and sqlite-dev packages installed)

```
sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby
```

works like a charm.

Comment: worked for me too. sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev libsqlite3-dev

Answer (score 2):

From [sqlite3-ruby gem can't find sqlite3.h on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800243/sqlite3-ruby-gem-cant-find-sqlite3-h-on-ubuntu):

You also need to install gcc itself, so in total it would be:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc libsqlite3-dev ruby1.8-dev
sudo gem install sqlite3
```

Apparently you get a wrong error pointing to a missing sqlite3.h when the actual problem is missing gcc itself.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a better answer from [HEROKU - cannot run git push heroku master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963561/heroku-stack-cedar-cannot-run-git-push-heroku-master)

Since you can't use sqlite3 on heroku add this to your Gemfile:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to add `--` to separate `configure` parameters from `gem` parameters.

instead of

```
sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby --without-sqlite3-include=/usr/include
```

try this, all on one line, make sure to include `--` after the last `gem` parameter and before `configure` parameters:

```
sudo gem install sqlite3 --
--with-sqlite3-lib=/somewhere/local/lib
--with-sqlite3-include=/somewhere/local/include
```

This should get you around this error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
    invalid option: --without-sqlite3-include=/usr/include
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed - big thanks to this submitter!

Answer (score 1):

Had this same problem and the following worked for me:

compile sqlite3 as static library, install somewhere in your home directory and then provide that option for the gem install process.

Go to the download page and grab the source. Most recent version at this time is http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-autoconf-3070400.tar.gz

tar -xf on the file or do whatever you normally do to uncompress; enter directory

./configure --disable-shared --enable-static --prefix=/some/path/in/my/home

compile, install, and when you're installing the gem...

gem install sqlite3-ruby -- --with-sqlite3-dir=/some/path/in/my/home

Answer (score 1):

None of the above mentioned solution worked for me, even after installing `ruby2.5-dev` and `libsqlite3-dev`. Then tried using `PostgreSql` instead of `sqlite`. That worked fine. To use `PostgreSql` instead of sqlite use this command when creating `rails` project.

```
rails [_VERSION_] new project_name -d postgresql
```

If you want to use `MySql` then use `mysql` instead of `postgresql`.

```
rails [_VERSION_] new project_name -d mysql
```

Else you can try without `sqlite`.

```
bundle install --without sqlite
```

Answer (score 0):

Not `--without-sqlite3-include=/usr/include`, but `--with-sqlite3-include=/usr/include`.

Comment: If sqlite3.h is really missing and not in /usr/include as you said, then you can install it with: sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev

Comment: I have already done this.. It doesn't help. I have sqlite3 and libsqlite3-dev installed.

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact same problem I had a few weeks ago. I found out I needed to download the most recent headers/libraries from the SQLite Download Page. Try it out, hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was solved by getting mkmf, which is in ruby1.8-dev.

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.8-dev
```

Thanks to [mentalized](http://mentalized.net/journal/2006/01/24/no_such_file_to_load_mkmf/) for that one.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Danya Vershinin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3458624/2481708) & [EnotionZ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4568835/2481708).

If can't use apt-get:

1. compile & install sqlite3 from sources by specifying your own "prefix" path.
   More information can be found in the README.
2. Then passed this path to the sqlite3-ruby installer (don't forget the "--").

Answer (score 0):

You have broken version of RVM. Ubuntu does something to RVM that produces lots of errors, the only safe way of fixing for now is to: sudo apt-get --purge remove ruby-rvm sudo rm -rf /usr/share/ruby … , if it does not help then restart your computer. install RVM: \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby --autolibs=enable --auto-dotfiles If you find you need some hand-holding, take a look at Installing Ruby on Ubuntu 12.04, which gives a bit more explanat

Answer (score 0):

Forget everything and do this,

run

```
yum install ruby-devel sqlite sqlite-devel ruby-rdoc
yum install make gcc
gem install sqlite3-ruby
bundle install
```

That's for rhel, run same for ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I just downgraded to sqlite3-ruby '1.2.2'