# How do I install SQlite3 for Ruby on Rails while using RVM

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, ubuntu-10.10

I am new to programming and Ruby on Rails. Setting up my dev environment has been hell. My present issue is installing Sqlite 3.

When I do

```
$ bundle install
```

I get

```
 Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Using rake (0.8.7) 
Using abstract (1.0.0) 
Using activesupport (3.0.1) 
Using builder (2.1.2) 
Using i18n (0.4.2) 
Using activemodel (3.0.1) 
Using erubis (2.6.6) 
Using rack (1.2.1) 
Using rack-mount (0.6.13) 
Using rack-test (0.5.7) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.24) 
Using actionpack (3.0.1) 
Using mime-types (1.16) 
Using polyglot (0.3.1) 
Using treetop (1.4.9) 
Using mail (2.2.15) 
Using actionmailer (3.0.1) 
Using arel (1.0.1) 
Using activerecord (3.0.1) 
Using activeresource (3.0.1) 
Using bundler (1.0.10) 
Using thor (0.14.6) 
Using railties (3.0.1) 
Using rails (3.0.1) 
Installing sqlite3 (1.3.3) with native extensions /home/oo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:533:in `rescue in block in build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

        /home/oo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
or 'yum install sqlite3-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/oo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
    --with-sqlite3-dir
    --without-sqlite3-dir
    --with-sqlite3-include
    --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
    --with-sqlite3-lib
    --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib


Gem files will remain installed in /home/oo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/oo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
    from /home/oo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:511:in `block in build_extensions'
    from /home/oo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:486:in `each'
    from /home/oo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:486:in `build_extensions'
    from /home/oo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:159:in `install'
    from /home/oo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/source.rb:96:in `install'
    from /home/oo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/installer.rb:55:in `block in run'
    from /home/oo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `block in each'
    from /home/oo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
    from /home/oo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
    from /home/oo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/installer.rb:44:in `run'
    from /home/oo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
    from /home/oo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/cli.rb:226:in `install'
    from /home/oo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
    from /home/oo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
    from /home/oo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
    from /home/oo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
    from /home/oo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.10/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/oo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
    from /home/oo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
```

I am using Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458602/sqlite3-ruby-install-error-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing shared libraries to install sqlite3.

Probably one thing that most ROR install instructions or tutorials don't tell you is that when running on Linux you need shared libraries or if your a windows person dll's are missing or incompatible with the version you are trying to run.

I see you are running RVM also.  So you should try this.

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby
```

If you still have trouble installing the gem try this - drop the sudo in the line and just gem install

```
gem install sqlite3-ruby -- --with-sqlite3-dir=/usr/local/lib
```

Additionally it doesn't hurt to update all your libraries for Ubuntu.

Run this first before running the libraries for sqlite3:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It will probably take some minutes to run the update and upgrade. You can also run this from the Admin --> System area . There is a menu that allows you to run all library updates and checks for dependencies which may be missing.

You could also run the sqlite install from the system applications GUI, as it will check dependency programs which may also be needed.

Just remember when something doesn't install like the issue you are having with Ruby on Rails, it usually means that libraries are missing or the incorrect version needed.

Comment: @ianN I successfully did 'sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade' and 'sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'. But when I did 'sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby' I got the response 'sudo: gem: command not found'

Comment: @OoTheNigerian - sorry mate, forgot you are running RVM. I have updated my answer for you

Comment: @IanN. I cannot notice the change you made. sorry for being a bother.

Comment: @OoTheNigerian - I added a new line under sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby -- --with-sqlite3-dir=.....

Comment: Worked like charm. Thanks a bundle @IanN. I officially love StackOverflow.

Comment: When using RVM, [you can't use sudo to install gems](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rubies/rubygems/). `sudo` changes the environment so the gem will be installed into the root user's environment.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better answer from [HEROKU - cannot run git push heroku master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963561/heroku-stack-cedar-cannot-run-git-push-heroku-master)

Since you can't use sqlite3 on heroku add this to your Gemfile:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```