# Rails 3 - Bundle install not working anymore... a sqlite3 problem!

Tags: ruby-on-rails

some minutes ago i did a

```
bundle install git://github.com/vigetlabs/serialize_with_options.git
```

and now every time i try to make a "bundle install" i get this error:

```
> MacBook-di-Andrea:village abramo$
> bundle install http://rubygems.org
> Fetching source index for
> http://rubygems.org/ Installing rake
> (0.8.7)  Installing abstract (1.0.0) 
> Installing activesupport (3.0.5) 
> Installing builder (2.1.2)  Installing
> i18n (0.5.0)  Installing activemodel
> (3.0.5)  Installing erubis (2.6.6) 
> Installing rack (1.2.1)  Installing
> rack-mount (0.6.13)  Installing
> rack-test (0.5.7)  Installing tzinfo
> (0.3.24)  Installing actionpack
> (3.0.5)  Installing mime-types (1.16) 
> Installing polyglot (0.3.1) 
> Installing treetop (1.4.9)  Installing
> mail (2.2.15)  Installing actionmailer
> (3.0.5)  Installing arel (2.0.9) 
> Installing activerecord (3.0.5) 
> Installing activeresource (3.0.5) 
> Installing xml-simple (1.0.14) 
> Installing aws-s3 (0.6.2)  Using
> bundler (1.0.10)  Installing paperclip
> (2.3.8)  Installing thor (0.14.6) 
> Installing railties (3.0.5) 
> Installing rails (3.0.5)  Installing
> sqlite3 (1.3.3) with native extensions
> /Users/abramo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:529:in
> `rescue in block in build_extensions':
> ERROR: Failed to build gem native
> extension.
> (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)
> 
>         /Users/abramo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
> extconf.rb  checking for sqlite3.h...
> yes checking for
> sqlite3_libversion_number() in
> -lsqlite3... yes checking for rb_proc_arity()... yes checking for
> sqlite3_initialize()... yes checking
> for sqlite3_next_stmt()... yes
> checking for sqlite3_backup_init()...
> yes checking for
> sqlite3_column_database_name()... no
> checking for
> sqlite3_enable_load_extension()... no
> checking for
> sqlite3_load_extension()... no
> creating Makefile
> 
> make Makefile:148: *** target pattern
> contains no `%'.  Stop.
> 
> 
> Gem files will remain installed in
> /Users/abramo/village/http:/rubygems.org/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3
> for inspection. Results logged to
> /Users/abramo/village/http:/rubygems.org/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
>   from
> /Users/abramo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:507:in
> `block in build_extensions'   from
> /Users/abramo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:482:in
> `each'    from
> /Users/abramo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:482:in
> `build_extensions'    from
> /Users/abramo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:156:in
> `install'     from
> /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/source.rb:96:in
> `install'     from
> /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/installer.rb:55:in `block in run'     from
> /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in
> `block in each'   from
> /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in
> `each'    from
> /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in
> `each'    from
> /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/installer.rb:44:in `run'  from
> /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in
> `install'     from
> /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/cli.rb:226:in
> `install'     from
> /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in
> `run'     from
> /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in
> `invoke_task'     from
> /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'  from
> /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in
> `start'   from
> /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.10/bin/bundle:13:in
> `<top (required)>'    from
> /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/bundle:19:in
> `load'    from
> /Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/bundle:19:in
> `<main>'
```

Do you know how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question title to something more specific

Comment: Ok, done! Hope someone will help me figure this out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by deleting a folder in my project folder. I deleted a couple of hidden folders. So if something similar would happen to you (and you are on OS X) just type in your terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
killall Finder
```

After this you will see hidden folders in Finder. Enter your project folder and delete hidden folders one by one to discover what is the source of the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had the same issue and I fixed it by deleting the .bundle folder in my application.

Comment: i fixed it by deleting the .bundle folder also... it seems an aborted gem install corrupted that config file in that folder... I deleted it and ran bundle install.. happy days!

Answer (score 2):

seems like this is a sqlite3 install issue, Check this thread, hope you also have the same issue

[How do I install SQlite3 for Ruby on Rails while using RVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264234/how-do-i-install-sqlite3-for-ruby-on-rails-while-using-rvm)

HTH

cheers

sameera

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I figured out how to solve my mistake myself, it was another problem