# Push to Heroku - hanging Fetching http://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, activeadmin

I don't know why push to heroku failed. I tried pushing it many times, but it didn't work.

I use the following OS/tools:

- Windows 7
- rails version 4.0.3,
- ruby version 2
- Node.js
- Github
- Heroku

Here is the error I got:

```
$ git push heroku master
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 150, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (139/139), done.
Writing objects: 100% (150/150), 175.21 KiB | 190.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 150 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0)

Ruby app detected
Compiling Ruby/Rails
Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
Warning:
       Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
       Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
       This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
       In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your dependencies at
 all.
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile
       Installing dependencies using 1.5.2
       New app detected loading default bundler cache
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle -
-binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4
       Fetching http://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git

      Timed out compiling Ruby app (15 minutes)
      See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#time-limit

      To git@heroku.com:warm-stream-5170.git
      [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
      error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:warm-stream-5170.git'
```

The gemfile is as follows:

```
      source 'https://rubygems.org'
      gem 'rails', '4.0.3'
      gem 'sqlite3'
      gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
      gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
      gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
      gem 'jquery-rails'
      gem 'turbolinks'
      gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
      group :doc do
      gem 'sdoc', require: false
      end
      gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
      gem 'activeadmin-axlsx'
      gem 'devise'
      gem 'cancan'
      gem 'rolify'
```

Comment: Can you share your Gemfile in the question.

Comment: Maybe try look here http://stackoverflow.com/q/7963561/1021970

Answer (score 0):

Use this in Gemfile

```
gem 'activeadmin', :git => "git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git"
```

Also, for production use `pg`:

Remove `gem 'sqlite3'` and replace with the following code:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

Comment: Kriti/Girly girl, Thanks for the help, I got again the following error, it says push rejected, failed to compile. i got very long list error, i can not past it here. :(