# deploying rails app on heroku with postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I keep getting an error when i run

```
git push heroku master
```

this is the error i'm getting:

```
remote:        Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:        
remote:        /tmp/build_6084782c356fe559294d11bd3affdd4e/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
remote:        checking for sqlite3.h... no
remote:        sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',
remote:        'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
```

my config/database.yml looks like this:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: small_time_grocer_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: small_time_grocer_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: small_time_grocer_production
  username: small_time_grocer
  password: <%= ENV['SMALL_TIME_GROCER_DATABASE_PASSWORD']
```

my Gemfile is as follows:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.0'

gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'pg'


# devise gems
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'

# gem for error respond_to featurefrom responders gem
gem 'responders', '~> 2.0'

group :development, :test do

  gem 'byebug'

  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  gem 'spring'
end

ruby "2.1.5"
```

I don't have sqlite3 anywhere in the gemfile, but i still keep getting this error even after committing my changes and pushing to heroku. Any ideas?

I should also mention on the onset, that I didn't know about the -d flag for the rails new command. So i initially started the rails app with:

```
rails new <servername>
```

instead of :

```
rails new <servername> -d postgresql
```

Should i just start the app over only this time i initialize with postgresql? I can't figure out what configuration i'm missing in order to deploy.

Comment: Was sqlite ever in the Gemfile? If so, did you run `bundle install` after removing it?

Comment: yeah i had sqlite 3 in the gem file originally but i reran bundle install after taking it out, commited the Gemfile.lock than pushed to heroku, same error. Also, @mmichael is there a way to check if it us up to date?

Comment: Look at the `Gemfile.lock` contents and make sure there is no `sqlite3` there.

Comment: There were 2 instances of sqlite3 i removed them, commited and pushed, same error

Comment: Hmmm, it says i have a clean working direectory even after i made the changes to the Gemfile.lock

Comment: Have you tried spinning up a new Heroku app using your updated Gemfile?

Comment: I got it to work. Thanks all. It was a really silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `bundle update` (it will update the Gemfile.lock) and then push the changes again if there is any in `Gemfile` or `Gemfile,lock` .
and then try to deploy again.

Comment: try the solution given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963561/heroku-cannot-run-git-push-heroku-master

Comment: Yeah, i had tried that solution prior to posting this question. I guess I'll try and debug it some more

Answer (score 0):

I often need to delete the Gemfile.lock file before running bundle install or bundle update, in order to successfully generate a new Gemfile.lock file.

Then save changes to git for the push to Heroku:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "update gemfile"
git push heroku master
```