# Heroku deployment error simultaneously requires and rejects SQLite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-postgres

Doing a rails deployment, when I try to push to Heroku I get the following seemingly contradictory error which both states that it searched for and failed to find SQLite and that I need to install it, and that it found SQLite and thus rejected the push.

I followed [Heroku's suggested steps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3) for resolving this error to no avail. I have also tried the [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963561/heroku-cannot-run-git-push-heroku-master) of specifying SQLite for development and testing environments only, yielding the same error. I've checked the Gemfile.lock to ensure no other gems have an SQLite dependency. After each change I bundled, added/committed the code to git and then tried pushing to Heroku--I cannot get this error to change.

**Error**

```
Installing sdoc 0.4.1
remote:
remote:        Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:
remote:        /tmp/build_c866fb9c2a0cb2ec1b0a1f43e464129e/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
remote:        checking for sqlite3.h... no
remote:        sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',
remote:        'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
remote:        and check your shared library search path (the
remote:        location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
remote:        *** extconf.rb failed ***
remote:        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
remote:        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
remote:        need configuration options.
remote:
remote:        Provided configuration options:
remote:        --with-opt-dir
remote:        --without-opt-dir
remote:        --with-opt-include
remote:        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
remote:        --with-opt-lib
remote:        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
remote:        --with-make-prog
remote:        --without-make-prog
remote:        --srcdir=.
remote:        --curdir
remote:        --ruby=/tmp/build_c866fb9c2a0cb2ec1b0a1f43e464129e/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby
remote:        --with-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --without-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --with-sqlite3-include
remote:        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
remote:        --with-sqlite3-lib
remote:        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/
remote:
remote:
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_c866fb9c2a0cb2ec1b0a1f43e464129e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11 for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to /tmp/build_c866fb9c2a0cb2ec1b0a1f43e464129e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
remote:        An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.11), and Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
remote:  !
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote:
remote: !   Push rejected to <redacted>.
```

**Gem file**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'

  #User management and authentication gem
  gem 'devise', '~> 3.5.2'

  #Parallax library
  gem 'skrollr-rails'

  group :production do
    gem 'pg'
  end
  # group :development, :test do
  #     gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.11'
  # end


end
```

**Gemfile.lock**

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.2.1)
      actionpack (= 4.2.1)
      actionview (= 4.2.1)
      activejob (= 4.2.1)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (4.2.1)
      actionview (= 4.2.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.1)
      rack (~> 1.6)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
    actionview (4.2.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
    activejob (4.2.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.1)
      globalid (>= 0.3.0)
    activemodel (4.2.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.2.1)
      activemodel (= 4.2.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.1)
      arel (~> 6.0)
    activesupport (4.2.1)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    arel (6.0.3)
    bcrypt (3.1.10)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    builder (3.2.2)
    byebug (6.0.2)
    coffee-rails (4.1.0)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.9.1.1)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    devise (3.5.2)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
      responders
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.6.0)
    globalid (0.3.6)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    jbuilder (2.3.2)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.0.5)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.3)
    loofah (2.0.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.6.3)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3)
    mime-types (2.6.2)
    mini_portile (0.6.2)
    minitest (5.8.1)
    multi_json (1.11.2)
    nokogiri (1.6.6.2)
      mini_portile (~> 0.6.0)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    pg (0.18.1)
    rack (1.6.4)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.2.1)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.1)
      actionpack (= 4.2.1)
      actionview (= 4.2.1)
      activejob (= 4.2.1)
      activemodel (= 4.2.1)
      activerecord (= 4.2.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.1)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.1)
      sprockets-rails
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.7)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.2)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    railties (4.2.1)
      actionpack (= 4.2.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.1)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.4.2)
    rdoc (4.2.0)
      json (~> 1.4)
    responders (2.1.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0, < 5)
    sass (3.4.19)
    sass-rails (5.0.4)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    sdoc (0.4.1)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      rdoc (~> 4.0)
    skrollr-rails (0.6.29)
      rails (>= 3.1.0)
    spring (1.4.0)
    sprockets (3.4.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (2.3.3)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (2.0.1)
    turbolinks (2.5.3)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (2.7.2)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    warden (1.2.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    web-console (2.2.1)
      activemodel (>= 4.0)
      binding_of_caller (>= 0.7.2)
      railties (>= 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  byebug
  coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0)
  devise (~> 3.5.2)
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jquery-rails
  pg
  rails (= 4.2.1)
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
  skrollr-rails
  spring
  sqlite3 (= 1.3.11)
  turbolinks
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (~> 2.0)
```

**database.yml**

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: my_database_development

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: my_database_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: my_database_production
```

**Bundle install output**

```
:> bundle install
Using rake 10.4.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.3
Using minitest 5.8.1
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using activesupport 4.2.1
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile 0.6.2
Using nokogiri 1.6.6.2
Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
Using loofah 2.0.3
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2
Using actionview 4.2.1
Using rack 1.6.4
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using actionpack 4.2.1
Using globalid 0.3.6
Using activejob 4.2.1
Using mime-types 2.6.2
Using mail 2.6.3
Using actionmailer 4.2.1
Using activemodel 4.2.1
Using arel 6.0.3
Using activerecord 4.2.1
Using bcrypt 3.1.10
Using debug_inspector 0.0.2
Using binding_of_caller 0.7.2
Using byebug 6.0.2
Using coffee-script-source 1.9.1.1
Using execjs 2.6.0
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 4.2.1
Using coffee-rails 4.1.0
Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
Using responders 2.1.0
Using warden 1.2.3
Using devise 3.5.2
Using multi_json 1.11.2
Using jbuilder 2.3.2
Using jquery-rails 4.0.5
Using pg 0.18.1
Using bundler 1.9.4
Using sprockets 3.4.0
Using sprockets-rails 2.3.3
Using rails 4.2.1
Using rdoc 4.2.0
Using sass 3.4.19
Using tilt 2.0.1
Using sass-rails 5.0.4
Using sdoc 0.4.1
Using skrollr-rails 0.6.29
Using spring 1.4.0
Using turbolinks 2.5.3
Using uglifier 2.7.2
Using web-console 2.2.1
Bundle complete! 14 Gemfile dependencies, 59 gems now installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Comment: What is the output from `bundle install`?

Comment: @BenY I added the bundles install output into the post.

Comment: Note: even when I remove SQLite from the gemlock, bundle, add/commit/push I get the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Heroku runs uses PG for DB.

In your gem file under outside the "development and test do" add the gem PG and move the SQL Gem into your development section.

Push and commit then deploy to heroku.

Once deployed do "heroku run rake DB migrate" and that should get your DB up and running.