# Can't push rails app to heroku because of sqlite3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sqlite

I am trying to push my app to heroku, but I could not prevent it from installing sqlite3 - I believe this is what is causing the problem pushing it.

I have read and applied the following SO posts:

- [Deploying RoR app to Heroku with Sqlite3 fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897431/deploying-ror-app-to-heroku-with-sqlite3-fails)
- [HEROKU - cannot run git push heroku master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963561/heroku-cannot-run-git-push-heroku-master/7964625#7964625)
- [Unable to Deploy Rails App to Heroku, Gem Errors (SQLite3 and Gem Native Extension)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38667910/unable-to-deploy-rails-app-to-heroku-gem-errors-sqlite3-and-gem-native-extensi)

I have also made sure to commit my work:

```
git add .
git commit -m "sqlite3 problem"
git push heroku master
```

I tried deleting the Gemfile.lock and running both `bundle` and `bundle install` and add, commit, and pushed it to heroku, but still no luck.

This is inside my Gemfile:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
  gem 'faker', '~> 1.7', '>= 1.7.3'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.5'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.8'
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

Error log:

```
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.3.4
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.13.7
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
remote:        Installing i18n 0.8.1
remote:        Installing rake 12.0.0
remote:        Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
remote:        Installing minitest 5.10.1
remote:        Installing thread_safe 0.3.6
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.3
remote:        Installing erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Installing mini_portile2 2.1.0
remote:        Installing nio4r 2.0.0 with native extensions
remote:        Installing rack 2.0.1
remote:        Installing websocket-extensions 0.1.2
remote:        Installing mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
remote:        Installing arel 7.1.4
remote:        Installing connection_pool 2.2.1
remote:        Installing thor 0.19.4
remote:        Installing jwt 1.5.6
remote:        Installing method_source 0.8.2
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.12.1
remote:        Using bundler 1.13.7
remote:        Installing puma 3.8.2 with native extensions
remote:        Installing redis 3.3.3
remote:        Installing sqlite3 1.3.13 with native extensions
remote:        Installing tzinfo 1.2.3
remote:        Installing nokogiri 1.7.1 with native extensions
remote:        Installing rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Installing rack-protection 2.0.0
remote:        Installing sprockets 3.7.1
remote:        Installing websocket-driver 0.6.5 with native extensions
remote:        Installing mime-types 3.1
remote:        Installing foreman 0.84.0
remote:        Installing twilio-ruby 4.11.1
remote:        Installing activesupport 5.0.2
remote:        Installing sidekiq 5.0.0
remote:        Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:        current directory:
remote:        /tmp/build_cb97a281aec933a41e755d6b82c2e524/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/ext/sqlite3
remote:        /tmp/build_cb97a281aec933a41e755d6b82c2e524/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/bin/ruby -r
remote:        ./siteconf20170606-219-133actd.rb extconf.rb
remote:        checking for sqlite3.h... no
remote:        sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'brew install sqlite3',
remote:        'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
remote:        and check your shared library search path (the
remote:        location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
remote:        *** extconf.rb failed ***
remote:        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
remote:        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
remote:        need configuration options.
remote:        Provided configuration options:
remote:        --with-opt-dir
remote:        --without-opt-dir
remote:        --with-opt-include
remote:        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
remote:        --with-opt-lib
remote:        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
remote:        --with-make-prog
remote:        --without-make-prog
remote:        --srcdir=.
remote:        --curdir
remote:        --ruby=/tmp/build_cb97a281aec933a41e755d6b82c2e524/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
remote:        --with-sqlite3-config
remote:        --without-sqlite3-config
remote:        --with-pkg-config
remote:        --without-pkg-config
remote:        --with-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --without-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --with-sqlite3-include
remote:        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
remote:        --with-sqlite3-lib
remote:        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
remote:        To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
remote:        be found here:
remote:        /tmp/build_cb97a281aec933a41e755d6b82c2e524/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.3.13/mkmf.log
remote:        extconf failed, exit code 1
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in
remote:        /tmp/build_cb97a281aec933a41e755d6b82c2e524/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13
remote:        for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to
remote:        /tmp/build_cb97a281aec933a41e755d6b82c2e524/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.3.13/gem_make.out
remote:        An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.13), and Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.13'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:        Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
remote:        Installing i18n 0.8.1
remote:        Installing rake 12.0.0
remote:        Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
remote:        Installing minitest 5.10.1
remote:        Installing thread_safe 0.3.6
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.3
remote:        Installing erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Installing mini_portile2 2.1.0
remote:        Installing nio4r 2.0.0 with native extensions
remote:        Installing rack 2.0.1
remote:        Installing websocket-extensions 0.1.2
remote:        Installing mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
remote:        Installing arel 7.1.4
remote:        Installing connection_pool 2.2.1
remote:        Installing thor 0.19.4
remote:        Installing jwt 1.5.6
remote:        Installing method_source 0.8.2
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.12.1
remote:        Using bundler 1.13.7
remote:        Installing puma 3.8.2 with native extensions
remote:        Installing redis 3.3.3
remote:        Installing sqlite3 1.3.13 with native extensions
remote:        Installing tzinfo 1.2.3
remote:        Installing nokogiri 1.7.1 with native extensions
remote:        Installing rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Installing rack-protection 2.0.0
remote:        Installing sprockets 3.7.1
remote:        Installing websocket-driver 0.6.5 with native extensions
remote:        Installing mime-types 3.1
remote:        Installing foreman 0.84.0
remote:        Installing twilio-ruby 4.11.1
remote:        Installing activesupport 5.0.2
remote:        Installing sidekiq 5.0.0
remote:        Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:        
remote:        current directory:
remote:        /tmp/build_cb97a281aec933a41e755d6b82c2e524/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/ext/sqlite3
remote:        /tmp/build_cb97a281aec933a41e755d6b82c2e524/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/bin/ruby -r
remote:        ./siteconf20170606-219-133actd.rb extconf.rb
remote:        checking for sqlite3.h... no
remote:        sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'brew install sqlite3',
remote:        'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
remote:        and check your shared library search path (the
remote:        location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
remote:        *** extconf.rb failed ***
remote:        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
remote:        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
remote:        need configuration options.
remote:        
remote:        Provided configuration options:
remote:        --with-opt-dir
remote:        --without-opt-dir
remote:        --with-opt-include
remote:        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
remote:        --with-opt-lib
remote:        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
remote:        --with-make-prog
remote:        --without-make-prog
remote:        --srcdir=.
remote:        --curdir
remote:        --ruby=/tmp/build_cb97a281aec933a41e755d6b82c2e524/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
remote:        --with-sqlite3-config
remote:        --without-sqlite3-config
remote:        --with-pkg-config
remote:        --without-pkg-config
remote:        --with-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --without-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --with-sqlite3-include
remote:        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
remote:        --with-sqlite3-lib
remote:        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
remote:        
remote:        To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
remote:        be found here:
remote:        
remote:        /tmp/build_cb97a281aec933a41e755d6b82c2e524/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.3.13/mkmf.log
remote:        
remote:        extconf failed, exit code 1
remote:        
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in
remote:        /tmp/build_cb97a281aec933a41e755d6b82c2e524/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13
remote:        for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to
remote:        /tmp/build_cb97a281aec933a41e755d6b82c2e524/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.3.13/gem_make.out
remote:        
remote:        An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.13), and Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.13'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku:
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
```

Every single time, I keep seeing this line `Installing sqlite3 1.3.13 with native extensions` and I believe that is what caused the error, even though I don't have sqlite3 in production. I have also tried removing sqlite3 altogether from Gemfile and have only `gem pg`, but it still somehow installs sqlite3 when I push it to heroku.

How can I push the app to heroku successfully?

**EDIT:**

The problem is solved (well, technically not - I am still having trouble pushing, *but* the sqlite3 error disappeared, and that's the gist of this question). Here is what I did wrong: I was working on other local branch when I see the error message, let's say *iggy-branch-2*. I did my `git add ., git commit -m "some message", and git push heroku master` on this branch. When I switched back to `master` branch and `git merge iggy-branch-2`, and after I `git push heroku master`, it stopped trying to install sqlite3. It appears that when I push to heroku, it looks for `gemfile.lock` inside master branch (someone correct me if I'm wrong).

The comments and answer here gave me the insight that the only way to update `gemfile.lock` is really just to bundle it up. I figured I did all the right thing, so I decided to try switching branches.

Take-home: make sure my `master` branch is up-to-date. Seems like Heroku looks there for gemfile info.

Thanks, everyone!

Comment: do a "bundle install" to update the Gemfile.lock. Can you paste your database.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because herouku uses your gemfile.lock to know the gems and versions to use instead of the gemfile, you must:

1. run a bundle install locally to update your gemfile.lock
2. commit and push that change to git(hub)
3. push to heroku.

Good luck!

Edit: Also, make sure to include your gemfile.lock to git, although that's kind of obvious

Answer (score 0):

When you do `git push heroku master`, it pushes your local *master branch* onto the master branch of the heroku remote (no matter which local branch is currently checked out).

If you are working on a different branch, say 'feature/foo' and you want to deploy that branch, you need to tell git explicitly by doing `git push feature/foo:master`

Another way, from the [git push documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push):

> `git push origin HEAD:master`
>
> Push the current branch to the remote ref matching `master` in the `origin` repository. This form is convenient to push the current branch without thinking about its local name.

As you correctly guessed, the problem was that you were working on a branch but deploying master. This is why merging to master before deploying also solved the problem.