# gem install sqlite3 works, bundle install doesn't?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

```
root@localhost:~# which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
root@localhost:~# which gem
/usr/local/bin/gem
root@localhost:~# ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [i686-linux]
root@localhost:~# gem -v
1.7.2
root@localhost:~# 

root@localhost:~# gem install bundler
Successfully installed bundler-1.0.12
1 gem installed
......

root@localhost:~/www/blog# bundle install
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
......
```

> Installing sqlite3 (1.3.3) with native
>   extensions
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:533:in
>   `rescue in block in build_extensions':
>   ERROR: Failed to build gem native
>   extension.
>   (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)
>
> ```
>     /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
> ```
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /root/www/blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3
>   for inspection. Results logged to
>   /root/www/blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:511:in
>   `block in build_extensions'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:486:in`
>   each'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:486:in
>   `build_extensions'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:159:in`
>   install'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/source.rb:96:in
>   `install'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/installer.rb:55:in`block in run'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in
>   `block in each'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in`
>   each'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in
>   `each'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/installer.rb:44:in`run'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in
>   `install'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/cli.rb:225:in`
>   install'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in
>   `run'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in`
>   invoke_task'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in`
>   start'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.12/bin/bundle:13:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>           from /usr/local/bin/bundle:19:in`load'
>           from /usr/local/bin/bundle:19:in `'

Answer (score 1):

Both libsqlite3-0 and libsqlite3-dev are required for the sqlite3-ruby gem. To resolve potential issues you might face with OpenSSL, nokogiri, and SQLite3 on Ubuntu, run the following command (written on one line):

```
sudo aptitude install build-essential bison openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution discussed here: [sqlite3-ruby install error on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458602/sqlite3-ruby-install-error-on-ubuntu)