# ERROR: While executing gem ... (ArgumentError) IPv4 address expects 4 bytes but 1 bytes - Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rubygems

While compiling `bundle install`, I got this error:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/bartsabayton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150310-8631-16gdgvg.rb extconf.rb 
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking for sqlite3_libversion_number() in -lsqlite3... yes
checking for rb_proc_arity()... yes
checking for sqlite3_initialize()... yes
checking for sqlite3_backup_init()... yes
checking for sqlite3_column_database_name()... yes
checking for sqlite3_enable_load_extension()... yes
checking for sqlite3_load_extension()... yes
checking for sqlite3_open_v2()... yes
checking for sqlite3_prepare_v2()... yes
checking for sqlite3_int64 in sqlite3.h... yes
checking for sqlite3_uint64 in sqlite3.h... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling statement.c
statement.c: In function ‘bind_param’:
statement.c:261:7: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘RBIGNUM’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
statement.c:261:11: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)
statement.c:261:32: error: ‘SIZEOF_BDIGITS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
statement.c:261:32: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
statement.c: In function ‘reset_bang’:
statement.c:293:7: warning: variable ‘status’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
statement.c: In function ‘clear_bindings’:
statement.c:313:7: warning: variable ‘status’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
make: *** [statement.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/bartsabayton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1@e-law-landing/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/bartsabayton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1@e-law-landing/extensions/x86-linux/2.2.0/sqlite3-1.3.8/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.8), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.8'` succeeds before bundling.
```

So I did `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.8'`, but when doing this,

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (ArgumentError)
    IPv4 address expects 4 bytes but 1 bytes
```

I checked my rvm and,

RVM LIST:

```
bartsabayton@bartsabayton-All-Series:~/rails/landing$ rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-2.0.0-p0 [ i686 ]
   ruby-2.1.0 [ i686 ]
 * ruby-2.1.3 [ i686 ]
=> ruby-2.2.0-preview1 [ i686 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

I am using:

- Ubuntu 12.04
- Ruby 2.2.0preview1 (2014-09-17 trunk 47616) [i686-linux]

Please help. Need to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

You are using Ruby 2.2.0 and this particular version of sqlite3 (1.3.8) doesn't work on it.

So, you should install a newer version of sqlite3.

You can try:

```
gem install sqlite3
```

And make sure you installed `sqlite3` and `sqlite-devel` on your system.

*Note: As Ismael noticed, you should also update Ruby.*

Comment: I would also suggest to update the ruby version. As the OP is using a preview version

Comment: Ismael, I can't update my ruby version. We are not able to change because we have a protocol to follow. So I depend on 2.2.0 ruby version

Comment: `gem install sqlite3` installed a new version, so it installed 1.3.10. But it didn't fixed. I also use 1.3.7 but same error again.

Comment: And `sqlite3` and `sqlite-devel` are installed?

Comment: Like this? `sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev`

Comment: Yes, or sometimes it can be `libsqlite3-ruby`

Comment: `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libsqlite3-dev is already the newest version.
sqlite3 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 136 not upgraded.
`

Comment: `libsqlite3-dev` already installed. I also installed `libsqlite3-ruby` just now. Then, I bundle install again but I got same error. :(

Comment: Sorry, no idea what's wrong. It would be better to update ruby.

Comment: BartSabayton, The thing is that you are using a preview version of ruby-2.2.0 the final version came out on December so you should be able to use that version because that's the actual official 2.2.0 ruby version :)

Comment: Also try this `gem install sqlite3 -- --with-sqlite3-include=/usr/include`. Taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458602/sqlite3-ruby-install-error-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

You are using Ruby Higher versions like 2.x.x and this particular version of sqlite3 (1.3.8) have an issue.

so install sqlite3 manually using below command -

gem install sqlite3

and if still error you get delete your Gemfile.lock and then do bundle install, it works.