# gem install Sqlite3 erroring out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I'm trying to configure an environment to run rails on Windows 7 and I just can't seem to get sqlite3_native working to run "rails server".

I have followed the steps at:
[How do I install sqlite3 for Ruby on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480381/how-do-i-install-sqlite3-for-ruby-on-windows)

All the way to step 8, where I am failing. I run the command:

> gem install sqlite3 --platform=ruby -- --with-sqlite3-include=C:\RDK64\sqlite3\ --with-sqlite3-lib=C:\RDK64\sqlite3.libs\

And where that should successfully generate the ruby gem, instead I get this output:

```
C:\Users\owner\repo\cis467>gem install sqlite3 --platform=ruby -- --with-sqlite3
-include=C:\RDK64\sqlite3\ --with-sqlite3-lib=C:\RDK64\sqlite3\.libs\
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions with: '--with-sqlite3-include=C:\RDK64\sqlite3\ --wit
h-sqlite3-lib=C:\RDK64\sqlite3\.libs\'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/ext
/sqlite3
C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160908-69352-ouc8rr.rb extconf.rb --wi
th-sqlite3-include=C:\RDK64\sqlite3\ --with-sqlite3-lib=C:\RDK64\sqlite3\.libs\
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking for sqlite3_libversion_number() in -lsqlite3... yes
checking for rb_proc_arity()... yes
checking for rb_integer_pack()... yes
checking for sqlite3_initialize()... yes
checking for sqlite3_backup_init()... yes
checking for sqlite3_column_database_name()... no
checking for sqlite3_enable_load_extension()... yes
checking for sqlite3_load_extension()... yes
checking for sqlite3_open_v2()... yes
checking for sqlite3_prepare_v2()... yes
checking for sqlite3_int64 in sqlite3.h... yes
checking for sqlite3_uint64 in sqlite3.h... yes
creating Makefile

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
 be found here:

  C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.3.11/
mkmf.log

current directory: C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/ext/sql
ite3
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/ext/sql
ite3
make "DESTDIR="
compiling backup.c
In file included from backup.c:3:0:
./sqlite3_ruby.h:32:21: fatal error: sqlite3.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [backup.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite
3-1.3.11 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0
/sqlite3-1.3.11/gem_make.out
```

The mkmf file read as follows:

```
find_header: checking for sqlite3.h... -------------------- yes

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -IC:\RDK64\sqlite3\ -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby23-x64/lib -LC:\RDK64\sqlite3\.libs\ -L.      -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
6: {
7:   return 0;
8: }
/* end */

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -E -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -IC:\RDK64\sqlite3\ -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: #include <sqlite3.h>
/* end */

--------------------

find_library: checking for sqlite3_libversion_number() in -lsqlite3... -------------------- yes

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -IC:\RDK64\sqlite3\ -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby23-x64/lib -LC:\RDK64\sqlite3\.libs\ -L.      -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230 -lsqlite3  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:16:57: error: 'sqlite3_libversion_number' undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:16:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))sqlite3_libversion_number; return !p; }
/* end */

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -IC:\RDK64\sqlite3\ -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby23-x64/lib -LC:\RDK64\sqlite3\.libs\ -L.      -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230 -lsqlite3  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: extern void sqlite3_libversion_number();
17: int t(void) { sqlite3_libversion_number(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for rb_proc_arity()... -------------------- yes

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -IC:\RDK64\sqlite3\ -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby23-x64/lib -LC:\RDK64\sqlite3\.libs\ -L.     -lsqlite3  -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230 -lsqlite3  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_proc_arity; return !p; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for rb_integer_pack()... -------------------- yes

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -IC:\RDK64\sqlite3\ -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby23-x64/lib -LC:\RDK64\sqlite3\.libs\ -L.     -lsqlite3  -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230 -lsqlite3  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_integer_pack; return !p; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for sqlite3_initialize()... -------------------- yes

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -IC:\RDK64\sqlite3\ -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby23-x64/lib -LC:\RDK64\sqlite3\.libs\ -L.     -lsqlite3  -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230 -lsqlite3  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:16:57: error: 'sqlite3_initialize' undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:16:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))sqlite3_initialize; return !p; }
/* end */

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -IC:\RDK64\sqlite3\ -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby23-x64/lib -LC:\RDK64\sqlite3\.libs\ -L.     -lsqlite3  -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230 -lsqlite3  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: extern void sqlite3_initialize();
17: int t(void) { sqlite3_initialize(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for sqlite3_backup_init()... -------------------- yes

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -IC:\RDK64\sqlite3\ -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby23-x64/lib -LC:\RDK64\sqlite3\.libs\ -L.     -lsqlite3  -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230 -lsqlite3  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:16:57: error: 'sqlite3_backup_init' undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:16:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))sqlite3_backup_init; return !p; }
/* end */

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -IC:\RDK64\sqlite3\ -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby23-x64/lib -LC:\RDK64\sqlite3\.libs\ -L.     -lsqlite3  -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230 -lsqlite3  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: extern void sqlite3_backup_init();
17: int t(void) { sqlite3_backup_init(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for sqlite3_column_database_name()... -------------------- no

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -IC:\RDK64\sqlite3\ -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby23-x64/lib -LC:\RDK64\sqlite3\.libs\ -L.     -lsqlite3  -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230 -lsqlite3  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:16:57: error: 'sqlite3_column_database_name' undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:16:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))sqlite3_column_database_name; return !p; }
/* end */

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -IC:\RDK64\sqlite3\ -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby23-x64/lib -LC:\RDK64\sqlite3\.libs\ -L.     -lsqlite3  -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230 -lsqlite3  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Temp\ccHlMUDB.o: In function `t':
C:\Ruby23-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.3.0\gems\sqlite3-1.3.11\ext\sqlite3/conftest.c:17: undefined reference to `sqlite3_column_database_name'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: extern void sqlite3_column_database_name();
17: int t(void) { sqlite3_column_database_name(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for sqlite3_enable_load_extension()... -------------------- yes

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -IC:\RDK64\sqlite3\ -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby23-x64/lib -LC:\RDK64\sqlite3\.libs\ -L.     -lsqlite3  -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230 -lsqlite3  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:16:57: error: 'sqlite3_enable_load_extension' undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:16:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))sqlite3_enable_load_extension; return !p; }
/* end */

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -IC:\RDK64\sqlite3\ -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby23-x64/lib -LC:\RDK64\sqlite3\.libs\ -L.     -lsqlite3  -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230 -lsqlite3  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: extern void sqlite3_enable_load_extension();
17: int t(void) { sqlite3_enable_load_extension(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for sqlite3_load_extension()... -------------------- yes

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -IC:\RDK64\sqlite3\ -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby23-x64/lib -LC:\RDK64\sqlite3\.libs\ -L.     -lsqlite3  -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230 -lsqlite3  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:16:57: error: 'sqlite3_load_extension' undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:16:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))sqlite3_load_extension; return !p; }
/* end */

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -IC:\RDK64\sqlite3\ -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby23-x64/lib -LC:\RDK64\sqlite3\.libs\ -L.     -lsqlite3  -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230 -lsqlite3  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: extern void sqlite3_load_extension();
17: int t(void) { sqlite3_load_extension(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for sqlite3_open_v2()... -------------------- yes

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -IC:\RDK64\sqlite3\ -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby23-x64/lib -LC:\RDK64\sqlite3\.libs\ -L.     -lsqlite3  -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230 -lsqlite3  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:16:57: error: 'sqlite3_open_v2' undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:16:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))sqlite3_open_v2; return !p; }
/* end */

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -IC:\RDK64\sqlite3\ -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby23-x64/lib -LC:\RDK64\sqlite3\.libs\ -L.     -lsqlite3  -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230 -lsqlite3  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: extern void sqlite3_open_v2();
17: int t(void) { sqlite3_open_v2(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------
```

I trimmed some of this to allow the post. I will provide the rest in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `libsqlite3-dev`

```
apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

There is already an answer to same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3649005/4758119)

Comment: How do I get the package in widows, since I can't use 'apt-get install'

Comment: Or should I use mingw32