# Ubuntu: could not install sqlite3 - Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, sqlite3-ruby

I am using Ubuntu 20.10 and when trying to install the sqlite3 gem while creating a new rails project it throws:

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/max/.gem/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/ext/sqlite3
/snap/bin/ruby -I /snap/ruby/201/lib/ruby/3.0.0 -r ./siteconf20210114-11794-ctxcp1.rb extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking for pthread_create() in -lpthread... yes
checking for -ldl... yes
checking for sqlite3_libversion_number() in -lsqlite3... yes
checking for rb_proc_arity()... no
checking for rb_integer_pack()... no
checking for sqlite3_initialize()... yes
checking for sqlite3_backup_init()... yes
checking for sqlite3_column_database_name()... yes
checking for sqlite3_enable_load_extension()... yes
checking for sqlite3_load_extension()... yes
checking for sqlite3_open_v2()... yes
checking for sqlite3_prepare_v2()... yes
checking for sqlite3_int64 in sqlite3.h... yes
checking for sqlite3_uint64 in sqlite3.h... yes
creating Makefile

current directory: /home/max/.gem/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/ext/sqlite3
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /home/max/.gem/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/ext/sqlite3
make "DESTDIR="
compiling aggregator.c
compiling backup.c
compiling database.c
database.c: In function ‘rb_sqlite3_open_v2’:
database.c:38:9: warning: unused variable ‘flags’ [-Wunused-variable]
   38 |   VALUE flags;
      |         ^~~~~
database.c: In function ‘exec_batch’:
database.c:726:57: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘sqlite3_exec’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  726 |     status = sqlite3_exec(ctx->db, StringValuePtr(sql), hash_callback_function, callback_ary, &errMsg);
      |                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                         |
      |                                                         int (*)(VALUE,  int,  char **, char **) {aka int (*)(long unsigned int,  int,  char **, char **)}
In file included from ./sqlite3_ruby.h:25,
                 from database.c:1:
/usr/include/sqlite3.h:405:9: note: expected ‘int (*)(void *, int,  char **, char **)’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)(VALUE,  int,  char **, char **)’ {aka ‘int (*)(long unsigned int,  int,  char **, char **)’}
  405 |   int (*callback)(void*,int,char**,char**),  /* Callback function */
      |   ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
database.c:726:81: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘sqlite3_exec’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  726 |     status = sqlite3_exec(ctx->db, StringValuePtr(sql), hash_callback_function, callback_ary, &errMsg);
      |                                                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                                                 |
      |                                                                                 VALUE {aka long unsigned int}
In file included from ./sqlite3_ruby.h:25,
                 from database.c:1:
/usr/include/sqlite3.h:406:3: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘VALUE’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’}
  406 |   void *,                                    /* 1st argument to callback */
      |   ^~~~~~
database.c:728:57: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘sqlite3_exec’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  728 |     status = sqlite3_exec(ctx->db, StringValuePtr(sql), regular_callback_function, callback_ary, &errMsg);
      |                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                         |
      |                                                         int (*)(VALUE,  int,  char **, char **) {aka int (*)(long unsigned int,  int,  char **, char **)}
In file included from ./sqlite3_ruby.h:25,
                 from database.c:1:
/usr/include/sqlite3.h:405:9: note: expected ‘int (*)(void *, int,  char **, char **)’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)(VALUE,  int,  char **, char **)’ {aka ‘int (*)(long unsigned int,  int,  char **, char **)’}
  405 |   int (*callback)(void*,int,char**,char**),  /* Callback function */
      |   ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
database.c:728:84: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘sqlite3_exec’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  728 |     status = sqlite3_exec(ctx->db, StringValuePtr(sql), regular_callback_function, callback_ary, &errMsg);
      |                                                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                                                    |
      |                                                                                    VALUE {aka long unsigned int}
In file included from ./sqlite3_ruby.h:25,
                 from database.c:1:
/usr/include/sqlite3.h:406:3: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘VALUE’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’}
  406 |   void *,                                    /* 1st argument to callback */
      |   ^~~~~~
database.c: At top level:
cc1: note: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wno-self-assign’ may have been intended to silence earlier diagnostics
cc1: note: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wno-parentheses-equality’ may have been intended to silence earlier diagnostics
cc1: note: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wno-constant-logical-operand’ may have been intended to silence earlier diagnostics
compiling exception.c
compiling sqlite3.c
sqlite3.c: In function ‘bignum_to_int64’:
sqlite3.c:33:27: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘RBIGNUM’; did you mean ‘T_BIGNUM’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   33 | #   define RBIGNUM_LEN(x) RBIGNUM(x)->len
      |                           ^~~~~~~
sqlite3.c:35:20: note: in expansion of macro ‘RBIGNUM_LEN’
   35 |   const long len = RBIGNUM_LEN(value);
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~
sqlite3.c:33:37: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)
   33 | #   define RBIGNUM_LEN(x) RBIGNUM(x)->len
      |                                     ^~
sqlite3.c:35:20: note: in expansion of macro ‘RBIGNUM_LEN’
   35 |   const long len = RBIGNUM_LEN(value);
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~
sqlite3.c:40:19: error: ‘SIZEOF_BDIGITS’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘SIZEOF_INT’?
   40 |   if (len > 63 / (SIZEOF_BDIGITS * CHAR_BIT) + 1) return 0;
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                   SIZEOF_INT
sqlite3.c:40:19: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
sqlite3.c:42:11: error: unknown type name ‘BDIGIT’
   42 |     const BDIGIT *digits = RBIGNUM_DIGITS(value);
      |           ^~~~~~
sqlite3.c:42:28: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘RBIGNUM_DIGITS’; did you mean ‘RBIGNUM_SIGN’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   42 |     const BDIGIT *digits = RBIGNUM_DIGITS(value);
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                            RBIGNUM_SIGN
sqlite3.c:42:28: warning: initialization of ‘const int *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
sqlite3.c:43:5: error: unknown type name ‘BDIGIT’; did you mean ‘ISDIGIT’?
   43 |     BDIGIT blast = digits[len-1];
      |     ^~~~~~
      |     ISDIGIT
sqlite3.c:44:5: error: unknown type name ‘BDIGIT’; did you mean ‘ISDIGIT’?
   44 |     BDIGIT bmax = (BDIGIT)1UL << (63 % (CHAR_BIT * SIZEOF_BDIGITS));
      |     ^~~~~~
      |     ISDIGIT
sqlite3.c:44:20: error: ‘BDIGIT’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘ISDIGIT’?
   44 |     BDIGIT bmax = (BDIGIT)1UL << (63 % (CHAR_BIT * SIZEOF_BDIGITS));
      |                    ^~~~~~
      |                    ISDIGIT
sqlite3.c:44:27: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before numeric constant
   44 |     BDIGIT bmax = (BDIGIT)1UL << (63 % (CHAR_BIT * SIZEOF_BDIGITS));
      |                           ^~~
sqlite3.c: At top level:
cc1: note: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wno-self-assign’ may have been intended to silence earlier diagnostics
cc1: note: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wno-parentheses-equality’ may have been intended to silence earlier diagnostics
cc1: note: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wno-constant-logical-operand’ may have been intended to silence earlier diagnostics
make: *** [Makefile:245: sqlite3.o] Fehler 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/max/.gem/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/max/.gem/extensions/x86_64-linux/3.0.0/sqlite3-1.4.2/gem_make.out
```

Sqlite3 version installed is 3.33.0.

I originally installed ruby via snap when first running into the issue. Then found some threads indicating that installion ruby via rbenv might help. Tried that but it didn't work so I removed rbenv again and tried to clean .bashrc.

Seems some flag value is not properly set or unused but have no clue how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to install the SQLite3 development headers.

`sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev`

Originally answered by [marshluca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/226025/marshluca) in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3649005/3104371

Comment: That didn't help, libsqlite3-dev was already installed. Contrary to the linked thread all necessary sqlite3 files seem to be present on my system accroding to the error message. But I just realize that rb_proc_arity() and rb_integer_pack() seem to be missing.
Any idea with which gem they come?